# java primefaces auto update image

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, primefaces

i have an application which displays charts from yahoo finance, i wish to update the charts everytime they change online. below is my code.

```
<table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        <b>Nifty 50</b><br/>
                        <b><h:outputText value="#{equityBean.niftyChange}"/></b><br/>
                        <b><h:outputText value="#{equityBean.niftyChangePer}"/></b><br/>
                        <b><h:outputText value="#{equityBean.niftyLTP}"/></b></td>
                <td><img src="http://ichart.yahoo.com/t?s=^NSEI"/></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td> 
                    <b>BSE Sensex</b><br/>
                    <b><h:outputText value="#{equityBean.sensexChange}"/></b><br/>
                    <b><h:outputText value="#{equityBean.sensexChangePer}"/></b><br/>
                    <b><h:outputText value="#{equityBean.sensexLTP}"/></b></td>
                <td><img src="http://ichart.yahoo.com/t?s=^BSESN"/></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td> 
                     <b>Gold</b><br/>
                    <b><h:outputText value="#{equityBean.sensexChange}"/></b><br/>
                    <b><h:outputText value="#{equityBean.sensexChangePer}"/></b><br/>
                    <b><h:outputText value="#{equityBean.sensexLTP}"/></b></td>
                <td><img src="http://ichart.yahoo.com/t?s=GCQ12.CMX"/></td>
                </tr>


                </table>
```

how do i do it with p:ajax? or is trhere any other way except schedulers?
**edited**

```
<p:poll interval="3"   
               listener="#{equityBean.sensexChange}" update=":frm" />
```

frm is the id of form, i have displayed date in the form but it doesnt update

```
 <h:form id="frm">

        <h:outputText value="#{equityBean.tdate}"/>
```

**edited again:**

```
public String getSensexChange() {
     setIndex("^BSESN");
    return sensexChange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the p:pool component, which makes ajax calls in a specified interval. Example:

```
<p:poll interval="3"   
            listener="#{counterBean.increment}" update="txt_count" />
```

You can see it in action [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf).

Comment: pls refer to my edited question, i used poll but it doesnt work

Comment: is the p:poll inside a form? what does the sensexChange method do? please update code snippets too

Comment: yes the poll is inside form, i have edited my question again to include the code snippet of sensexChange.

Comment: why are you returning a string from a listener method? they should be void. what do you expect to happen? the poll is in the same form as the other components? why should the date be updated? you are not updating it in the listener method..